# Angular animation error - Reduce of empty array with no initial value

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-animation

When adding animation to a component I get the following error in the console:

`Reduce of empty array with no initial value`

My Angular Version: **2.0.0**

The animation code:

```
animations: [
    trigger('routerTransition', [
        state('void', style({ position: 'fixed', width: '100%' })),
        state('*', style({ position: 'fixed', width: '100%' })),
        transition(':enter', [
            style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' }),
            animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }))
        ]),
        transition(':leave', [
            style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }),
            animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }))
        ])
    ])
]
```

The error:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that I was using the new animation aliases introduced in Angular version 2.1.0, I was following [this](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/angular-2-animate-router-transitions-6de179e00204#.wpeias7mf) example I did not realize my Angular version was not the same as in the example.

After digging through the call-stack I found that the actual error was:

**`the provided :enter is not of a supported format`**

It would have been helpful if this error was logged in the console.

**Upgrading to Angular 2.1.0 resolved the error.**

Extract from the release notes:

> Animation in Angular has been enhanced by adding  :enter and :leave aliases for the common void => * and * => void state changes. The transition API documentation has been updated with these aliases.